# How to add whatsapp share button on blogger

Tags: blogger, whatsapp

I want to add WhatsApp share button on my blog. I am using

```html
 <a href="whatsapp://send?text=https://onlinejnr.blogspot.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share in Whatsapp</a>
```

I want to share the current post URL in the `text` query parameter, not my blog address `https://onlinejnr.blogspot.com`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a look at [How to create Minimal, Compete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. You should although explain what you've tried so far and what exactly is your project you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

That will require modifying the `href` attribute and using a data tag ( aka `data:post.url`). The new code will look like -

```html
<a expr:href='"whatsapp://send?text=" + data:post.url' data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share in Whatsapp</a>
```

Comment: You was faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to what @PrayagVerma said, you can use great services for all type of share links like [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com).

This code also works:

```
<a expr:href='"whatsapp://send?text=TEXT-GOES-HERE" + data:post.url' data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share in Whatsapp</a>
```

You can add this to your HTML code of the blog. But my sole recommendation would be to use many of the services available on the internet. That's much easy and useful for all kind of sharing + no code is used ;)